# MPhiljay Barchart in android

Tags: mpandroidchart

In Barchart show x values from column belongs to one label more than 2 two but should be one.

```
viewModel.reportMounthData.observe(this, Observer { reportModelList->
            val barChart = binding.idBarChartMounth
            barChart.setScaleEnabled(false)
            val entries: ArrayList<BarEntry> = ArrayList()

            var i=0
            reportModelList.forEach { reportModel->
                entries.add(BarEntry(reportModel.YigilganBonus.toFloat(), i))
                i++
            }

            val bardataset = BarDataSet(entries, "Oylik maoshlar miqdori")

            val labels = ArrayList<String>()
            reportModelList.sortedBy { it.oy }.forEach { reportModel ->
                labels.add(mounthSalary(reportModel.oy))
            }

            val data = BarData(labels, bardataset)
            barChart.data = data // set the data and list of labels into chart
            barChart.setDescription("\uD83D\uDEE0 Oylik maosh statistikasi") // set the description
//            bardataset.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS)
            barChart.animateY(2500)
        })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDbyo.jpg)

Comment: It seems your question needs more explanation to specify what the problem exactly is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works perfectly until the values ​​reach 6. If there are more than 6, a defect may occur naturally. they said that the main reason for this is that it will not fit on the screen